# Are there enough resources in Metro: Last Light to make exploration optional?

Tags: metro-last-light

From what I understand, *Metro: Last Light* is a semi-linear game where you have a general path to follow, but there might be a few rooms off to the side that you can explore for resources, back story, and whatnot.

If I played the game without much exploration and just took a straight path through the game, on medium/default difficulty, would it still be possible to complete the game while still being challenging but fair? Or does the game truly encourage exploration by making later levels very difficult unless you have enough of certain resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't explore that much on normal difficulty and it didn't seem too bad. Filters, the most problematic resource for me in the prequel, are much more plentiful in Last Light. At the end I had something like 55 minutes left of filter time. Also if you are run low on bullets you can always buy some from a merchant, or in sections with humans simply avoid them or take them down using stealth.

Comment: Excellent thanks, that's helpful. In *most* games, I'm a pack rat and so I end up with way too many resources, so I figure if I played this game more "normally", it still shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: oddly enough I had less filters in this than the first

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to explore, to get through the game

BUT

You miss out on some rather interesting and creepy locations, and sometimes very powerful weapons.

Also: If you care for the good ending, you pretty much have to explore. I bet you have noticed that sometimes the screen gets a bit brighter, and you hear a noise.

This indicates that you did something, which counts towards the good ending.